# Using restful services in Oracle apex for twilio

Tags: plsql, twilio, oracle-apex

I need to create a oracle apex restful service module that is linked with my phone number on twilio and whenever someone sends a message to the twilio number it needs to save the body of the message into a table

What i need to know:

- The Http method i need to use like GET/POST/PUT/DELETE
- The PLSQL code i need to write the body of the message into the table

Answer (score 2):

***The Http method i need to use like GET/POST/PUT/DELETE***

Once you've created your endpoint connect it to the webhook Twilio provides. I.e. in the Twilio Dashboard select the active number and under `Messaging` `CONFIGURE WITH` select `Webhooks, ...` and under `A MESSAGE COMES IN` select `Webhook` and use your Url. By default Twilio will do a `POST` but you can select whether you want it to do a `POST` or `GET` there.

***The PLSQL code i need to write the body of the message into the table***

Twilio has [lots of examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python) but nothing for PL/SQL yet. In essence you would need to respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml) if you want to return something to your user but that doesn't seem necessary in your case (so an empty TwiML response with `200` suffices). All you need to figure out is how to unpack the `POST` request you receive and how to access the body. From the doc:

> Twilio makes HTTP requests to your application just like a regular web browser, in the format application/x-www-form-urlencoded. By including parameters and values in its requests, Twilio sends data to your application that you can act upon before responding.

So you would need to unpack the request parameters and get what's in the `Body` (see doc) and store it in your database. If I remember correctly you need to define your PL/SQL procedure with the right parameters and that's it. This example here https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=9487:65 should get you there.

Comment: I think the URL you meant was:  https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=9487:65

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out @JoelR.Kallman , I could've sworn it was working yesterday.